# Sharepoint announcements sorted by userfield1 not sorting

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

So I've got a basic sharepoint foundations 2010 site. I've created a view where I want two particular announcements to stay on top. I've added a field to sort by (UserField1) and set the value on the two announcements to A and B. When I change the default view to "SortedView,"  they still show up in order as most recently edited. So if I edited an announcement that didn't even have a value for UserField1, it would appear on top. As a caveat, when I go to the actual list of announcements, it is sorted, although they are down at the bottom of the list. It is sorted like this (X,X,X,A,B). If I change to descending order, it sorts like this (X,X,X,B,A). Any ideas?

Comment: And I want it to sort like this on the default page (A,B,X,X,X)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your sorting is only being applied on a specific view. My guess is that you updated the "AllItems" view. Which is why you are seeing some type of sorting on the main list.

Also as for the weird sorting you are experiencing (X,X,X,A,B), it is putting the blank fields before your actual fields as there is nothing to sort by so by default it puts them first.

My recommendation is that you change your indexing column to a number field and change the values to numbers rather than letters. Ie: 0, 1, 2, 3.... and you can treat it like an index. It is important that this column is of the type "numbers" so we can achieve proper sorting.

On the view you are working on, click >> Modify View and set the sorting to sort by your new IndexColumn and submit your changes.

Then, insure that your announcements list/web part is set to use the correct view by clicking >>Edit Web part >> Selected View >> select your custom view name.

Comment: Well, I've got it to where it will sort by a numbered field, but I'm still getting the same phenomenon (X,X,X,1,2,3) of null fields getting put to the top of the list then my 1,2,3 announcements.

Comment: I want it to put the null fields last (1,2,3,X,X,X) Is that possible? I don't want to have my user have to put in a value for the sorted field.

Comment: Can you try starting your index numbers at 0? To have them ordered with the null fields last, you will need to sort a value. If you want those specific announcements to always show last, why not give them large numbers like 50,51,52?
 As for you not wanting your user to have to put index values, how did you plan on sorting then?  Also, Have you considered adding an additional clause of sorting by the "Created" date?

Comment: I'm wanting them at the top, not the bottom. If the user doesn't put a value, then I want it to go to the top of the null list, but below the list with values.